# RecursiveDirectoryIterator 500 error

Tags: php, spl

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/var/www');
```

Any ideas why this would barf a 500? Already chown'd the directory to www-data.

The old way works fine, so I'm not thinking it's a file permission issue.

```
$dhandle = opendir('/var/www');
```

Comment: Always when developing and testing, make sure you have PHP displaying errors, which will give you more detail. At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: If you are doing this inside another namespace, you would need to use `\RecursiveDirectoryIterator()` with the preceding \, but that is only one of many possibilities. Check the error_reporting output.

Comment: THANKYOU!!!! Yes, I'm in another namespace!

Comment: \RecursiveDirectoryIterator() with the preceeding backslash is the solution